# in command line tools what is meant by "path"

Tags: command-line, path, nuget

I've come across many questions about grunt, node, git etc and someone usually asks if it has been added to you path.

Im installing nuget command line and it says:

```
"Make sure NuGet.exe is in your path"
```

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: I assume that they're talking about the environment variable called `PATH`. Folders included in that variable is accessible in the command line without specifying the full path. e.g. you can execute programs using just `program.exe`, rather than `some/path/to/executable/program.exe`.

Comment: You're welcome. I've expanded the comment a bit and added it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that they're talking about the environment variable called `PATH`.

Folders included in that variable is accessible in the command line without specifying the full path.

e.g. you can execute programs using just `program.exe`, rather than `some/path/to/executable/program.exe`.

You can find the PATH variable under `System` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Advanced tab` -> `Environment variables`. Then it will be visible in the top listbox in the column called `Variable`. From there you can add / remove folders as you see fit. Modify with caution.

Comment: Thanks, why modify with caution, what are the dangers?

Comment: The parts which are specific to (some versions of) Windows should be marked as such.  On U*x-y platforms, you would generally just `echo "$PATH"` at the system prompt to see its value, and `PATH=/new/dir:$PATH` to add `/new/dir` in front of the current value. (The syntax will be different if your shell is not Bourne-compatible.)

Comment: Indeed that this is specific for windows @tripleee, mostly because of OP question. Great addition for users of other OS'es and terminals.

Comment: If you put in a syntax error, you might end up in a confusing situation.  If you wreck the system path, commands you rely on in day-to-day use will be unreachable, though the workaround is to use their full path (e.g. `/bin/cat` instead of just `cat`; or `"C:\Windows\public\secret\confusingly\notepad.exe"` instead of just `notepad`.)

Comment: @DavidB There might be applications that depend on folders that are already present in the variable. Removing them might cause application to malfunction.